# mPDF library issue: Image size changed after creating pdf

Tags: pdf, mpdf

The pdf view in website is okay. But after creating the PDF, background size is changed. 
[image]

> Website view

[image]

> After creating the pdf using MPDF

Comment: This is an observation, not a question. Even if "the question is clear, right?" goes: show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems to me that the width of the html element you gave it can be changed by increasing or decreasing it.**